# Can I have a rowsource for a combobox with ranges from two different sheets?

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

---

I have a combobox, for which the value can be eather a type A or a type B thing. It is not important for the user which type it is, but the values are from different sheets.

I can't use Union for two ranges in different sheets, so I can't just asign the union to thw rowsource.

Is there a way of having both ranges in the combobox, without having them in the same sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it looping through the ranges and adding each item separately.

```
Dim rango1 As Range, rango2 As Range
Set rango1 = Sheets("1").Range("A1:A100")
Set rango2 = Sheets("2").Range("A1:A100")

For Each cell In rango1
    ComboBox1.AddItem cell.Text
Next
For Each cell In rango2
    ComboBox1.AddItem cell.Text
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

Because of your use of the term RowSource, I'm guessing this is a ComboBox on a UserForm.  If so, use the .List property instead, like so:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.ComboBox1.List = Array(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Text)

End Sub
```

Slightly more readable:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.ComboBox1.List = Array(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text, _
                              Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it is a ComboBox in a UserForm, but I think I wasn't clear about something; there is a list of type A things in sheet1 and a list of type B things on sheet2. Your method adds 2 items to the ComboBox, I want the union of both lists in the ComboBox.

Comment: +1 from me - although would have been manners for the OPer to up your answer!